# How to use functions of library in python?

Tags: python, information-gain

I want to use function which calculates conditional mutual information in python. I found a library 'mdentropy' implementing it. But when I tried to see the list of functions of mdentropy library by using command `dir(mdentropy)` it showed:

```
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

I opened the folder of mdenetropy but I am not able to see any python file having such functions there.

I downloaded the library from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mdentropy

My question basically is:

- How can I use the function to calculate Conditional Mutual Information from this library?
- Is there any other resource from where I can calculate this function?

Comment: I guess you installed it manually, could you use `pip` instead ?

Comment: Try to `import mdentropy.utils`: https://github.com/cxhernandez/mdentropy/blob/master/mdentropy/utils.py

Comment: Yes, I earlier installed it manually.Now I installed it using pip. What should I do next to see all of its functions so that I can use them.

Comment: See the [docs](http://msmbuilder.org/mdentropy/0.3.0/index.html). There  should be an example.

Comment: I tried to install it and I also find something wrong. My IDE (PyCharm) doesn't find any module named mdentropy, thus the import fails.

Comment: Thanks @Georgy  The link was hepful. I also found list of all functions here: http://msmbuilder.org/mdentropy/0.3.0/api.html